# MongoDB - Find documents which contain a particular value (python)

Tags: python, mongodb

Hey I want to find document in MongoDB which contain a given value (In python!). I'm using sth like that:

```
data = db[collection].findOne({"field_name" : {"$regex" :  "text"}})
```

It works but veery slowly (much slower than when I dont use $regex) and I'm wondering if it is possible to do it faster.

Comment: Have you considered using a text index?

Comment: Can you tell me what should I change? I'm pretty new in Python/Mongo

Comment: Please check out [official text index document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) as suggested by @Joe

Comment: @ray I type this: `db["collection"].create_index([("field_name", "text")])` and I got error: "not authorized on collection to execute comand {createIndexes:....)". I have wrong code or it is impossible to do this for my collection?

Comment: The exception message suggests that there is some permission-related issues. Please check your role in DB and cross-compare with [this official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#database-administration-roles_) to see if you have sufficient permission to create index

Comment: To keep this question focused on a single topic, consider asking a new question if a continued discussion on the create index issue is needed.

Comment: @ray how can I check my role in Python?

Comment: Please refer to my last comment to keep the question focused. Thanks.